# Setting button text doesn't work

Tags: android

I have this function :

```
public void setRandomValuesToButtons() {

    for( i=0;i<Rows; i++){
        for( j=0;j<Columns; j++){
            if (i==2 && j==1){
                continue;
            }
           // Random rand = new Random(); rand global variable
            rand_int = rand.nextInt(8);     


            buttonsTable[i][j]=new Button(this);
            buttonsTable[i][j].setText(Integer.toString(rand_int));
            buttonsVals[i][j]=rand_int;
        }
    }
```

But my buttons doesn't change their text. Why ?

Answer (score 2):

Because your buttons are not visible.

You are creating new Button instances by calling `new Button(this)`, but you don't actually add them to a visible layout by using `ViewGroup.addView()`. If they don't belong to a layout, they don't get displayed.

You probably want to use `findViewById()` to find existing buttons in your layout instead of creating new ones *(i assume you have the buttons already visible on the screen)*.

Comment: before calling setRandomValuesToButtons(), Im initializing every button, like this:
buttonsTable[0][1] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.B_l0c1);

now, if i erase the line " buttonsTable[i][j]=new Button(this);"
then I get the message that "application stopped unexpectedly"

Comment: That means that `findViewById()` has most likely returned `null`, because the view/button with that particular id could not be found. Make sure that you call `setContentView()` before you use `findViewById()`, that's a common mistake. If you don't have a layout/content view set, `findViewById()` doesn't find anything since it searches in the displayed ui hierachy.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Please mark this answer as correct if it was helpful to you *(since you didn't accept any answers yet you are probably unaware of the principle)*. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) how to do that. Thanks. :)